# Invalid Hook Call in React, but it works for others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am a very, very amateur programmer but I've been trying to get into JavaScript and ReactJS recently. It's not pretty and I don't know what most of the stuff does, but I figured I would follow a YouTube tutorial on some things that I was interested in, so [I found one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBr-PybP_9c) that I liked and followed it. However, at [8:52](https://youtu.be/tBr-PybP_9c?t=532), React threw up an Invalid Hook Call error. My problem is, even though I'm pretty sure the documentation has a solution, my amateur level doesn't allow for me to read it and understand it. Basically: I have no idea what the docs say. Below is an attached screenshot of the error (there's more, if anyone requests for me to scroll down) and the link to the completed code. If anyone could help, that would be amazing, but based on the number of comments and the lack of people acknowledging this error I would assume it's decently hard to reproduce. Also, if it's any help, I had to directly link to a few things (such as React-Bootstrap) because react wouldn't recognize just the plain words. Thank you in advance :)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPSJD.png)

[GitHub Code](https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Whatsapp-Clone)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question should not include images or remote code repositories. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve within a [example]. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.  Did I mention **How to ask a good question**?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I always recommend new users review [ask] to get an idea of how to form their questions. Using offsite examples is usually frowned upon because they may change, rendering the original questions useless. Could you include a [mcve] (ideally as an inline snippet)? Please note that the screenshot provided shows that the error React shows gives you three possibilities of what could be wrong-- investigating those options would be the first thing I would try if it were me.

Comment: It would help if you posted your code (and not the code that the tutorial provided)

Comment: @jlogan my code is exactly the same. I thought I might have messed up, but I actually downloaded the files and they still throw up the same error.

Comment: Okay, if your code is exactly the same, my next guess would be 1. delete your `node_modules` folder. 2. rerun `npm i`

Comment: @jlogan Wow. It turned out to be the "node_modules" folder in my server section that was causing the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is almost always a problem with #2 in your screenshot ("You might be breaking the rules of Hooks").  The most common error (though I didn't see this in your video) is calling hooks inside a child function of a function component, i.e.

```js
const Component = () => {
  // Good - hook is called at root of function component
  const selectorData = useSelector(getDataSelector);

  // Bad - hook is called inside a child function and has no context for hooks
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = useSelector(getDataSelector);
  }, []);

  return (
    // ...
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I may have found the problem. In my App.js script, I have a custom hook (useLocalStorage) nested within another function. Do you think this may have caused the problem? Here is the code:

`function App() {`

`const [id, setId] = useLocalStorage('id')`

Comment: That should be fine, it looks like it's on the root level of App.  The stack trace should have a better clue as to which file has the issue.  It's also possible, though less likely, that the problem is in a dependency.